# How Do I Write A Function That Counts Identical and Different IDs in Two Columns of Different Sizes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given a reference dataframe A of one column "ID" (50,000 rows),
and dataframes B, C, D, with column "ID" with 45,000 rows, 55,000, 70,000 rows respectively,
with each instance of "ID" being a large(seventeen digit) integer value,
with many identical values in all of the columns but not necessarily in the same row.

How do I write a function that counts the number of identical and different values in two of these columns?

COLUMNS:

A ['ID', 196, 202, 443, 781, 557]

B ['ID', 781, 488, 712, 202, 482, 311]

C ['ID', 889, 196, 302, 444]

D ['ID', 444, 202, 675]

INPUT:
A, B

OUTPUT:
Matches: 2 Difference: 3

Comment: May you provide us with a sample dataset and expected output for reference

Comment: identical values should reduce when you use `set()` - and then you can compare `len()` But it may gives little incorrect result when one value is more then 2 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try `.isin()`. Example with pd.Series:

```
A = pd.Series([196, 202, 443, 781, 557])

B = pd.Series([781, 488, 712, 202, 482, 311])

if len(A) >= len(B):
    matches = A.isin(B)
else:
    matches = B.isin(A)

mismatches = ~matches

print('matches: {}, mismatches: {}'.format(sum(matches), sum(mismatches))
```

comparing lengths is done so that the right number of mismatches is found. it would not matter for finding the right number of matches, of cours. Interpreting True as 1 and False as 0 allows summing up the numbers.